# I'm trying to write a script that setValue from another sheet to a new row every time it runs

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I want to pull data from another sheet and paste it in the same column in a new row. So basically every time the trigger runs the script, it adds another row making a list of values based on how often the script runs.

```
function chelsearepairlog2(){
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("IN-HOUSE CHELSEA WORKSHOP");
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet8");
  var currentrepairs = sheet1.getRange("S1").getValue();
  var lastRow = sheet2.getRange(1,1).getLastRow();
sheet2.getRange(lastRow+1,1).setValue(currentrepairs);
}
```

Comment: That's javascript, not java

Comment: You want to do that, so you did this. OK, but what is the question?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got something with grabbing your last row. This works fine for me to append a new row in column A with whatever is in cell `C1`. If you have values causing this to be the wrong row (such as a cell with a lower row outside of column A), you'd have to get more sophisticated.

```
function chelsearepairlog2(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("IN-HOUSE CHELSEA WORKSHOP");
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet8");
  var currentrepairs = sheet1.getRange("S1").getValue();
  var lastRow = sheet2.getLastRow();
  sheet2.getRange(lastRow+1,1).setValue(currentrepairs);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I do have other rows that go lower and it jumps to where those end. I had luck with using appendRow to a separate sheet then referencing that.